# Using :visited on links doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css

I have issue with pseudo class `:visited` on my links. Pseudo classes in my CSS are in right order, but `:visited` doesn't work. When I define it, all links on page automatically become "visited" although I haven't visited them.

Here is the code:

```css
.drop-menu a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #9d9d9c;
}
.drop-menu a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #174c90;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.drop-menu a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #512c6f;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.drop-menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #9e0243;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.drop-menu a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #781759;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="drop-menu">
  <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>
  <li><a href="">OUR WORK</a></li>
  <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"When I define it, all links on page automatically become "visited" although I haven't visited them"_ All your links point to the same empty location in your example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in href should be filled. so, `href="#"` . this is working.

```css
.drop-menu a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #9d9d9c;
}
.drop-menu a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #174c90;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.drop-menu a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #512c6f;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.drop-menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #9e0243;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.drop-menu a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #781759;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="drop-menu">
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">OUR WORK</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think if they are all filled with `#`, then once you visit the page (with `#` at the end of the URL), you have "visited" all of those pages, since they are the same. You need some unique URLs... If just playing around, try `#a`, `#b`, etc.